# How do I install libxvid for winff?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having trouble with ffmpeg. I want to convert files with Winff, but I can't get this error message:

```
Unknown encoder 'libxvid'
```

I tried recompiling ffmpeg from this [site.](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-ffmpeg-installation) I compiled it with no hiccups, so that's not the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why no libxvid

That site is just a ripoff of [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). The wiki does not install libxvid for two reasons:

1. libxvid outputs the old, legacy format MPEG-4 video. This format has been superceeded by more modern, more common, and more efficient formats such as H.264, H.265/HEVC, VP9. So libxvid was removed from the compile instructions long ago.
2. `ffmpeg` already has a built-in MPEG-4 video encoder. It is comparable in quality to libxvid. Usage example: `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v mpeg4 output.mp4`

## What you can do

Options, easiest to hardest:

- Use `-c:v mpeg4` instead of `-c:v libxvid` if you need MPEG-4 video.
- Use a more modern format such as H.264 with `-c:v libx264`.
- [Uninstall](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#RevertingChangesmadebythisGuide) your compiled `ffmpeg` and install the **ffmpeg** package from the Ubuntu repository. It has support for libxvid.
- Re-compile `ffmpeg`. You'll need to install the **libxvidcore-dev** package from the Ubuntu repository, then configure ffmpeg with `--enable-libxvid`.